# How can I install Windows on Pi 4 if I don't own a Windows computer?

Tags: pi-4, windows

I only have a Macbook and I have found that most installers for the Pi 4 are made to be run in Windows. Has anybody figured this out?

Comment: Seems to be a discrepancy between title and question: do you want to install Windows on a Pi4 or are you looking for an installer for Mac? Pi imager runs on a Mac (https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to run MS Window$ on a Raspberry Pi. The MS Window$ operating system is compiled to run on intel or compatible AMD processors. But A Raspberry Pi has an ARM processor. There is no MS Window$ available that is compiled for this processor.

There is [Windows 10 IoT Core](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55029) available but it is very limited and by far not a graphical desktop environment by its [Differences between Windows 10 Desktop and Windows 10 IoT Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/windows-iot-core#differences-between-windows-10-desktop-and-windows-10-iot-core).

Answer (score 0):

use a VM, virtualbox works, but I never got USB pathtrough to work even with the guest additions installed in the guest OS.

you can also use bootcamp, but I don't recommend it.

I tried every single thing I could think of to install win10 on my pi without a win10 computer, its impossible.

at the end I installed win10 on a old hp desktop.